# Retrieving list of users in my Android App through Parse that match Phone's contacts

Tags: android, parse-platform, chat

I am developing an Android chat messaging app using Parse where I am saving user's phone number, username, and password during the sign-up process that I have completed successfully.

Now, I want to fetch the list of users already saved under the Phone Contact list matching their phone numbers and display the users in a list view. I am stuck of writing the Parse query and showing the fetched users in a list view.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO].Please take time out for a [tour] and visit the [help]. You might also want to read [ask].

Comment: @Rehan So just check which phone numbers are saved in your parse server are in your contact list.

Comment: Actually I am newbie in android and I fetch successfully contact list of my phone book but how to compare with database contacts .

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is the following:

1. Get all your contacts phone numbers into a list
2. In ParseQuery use the following method (from parse docs website)

[image]

Please make sure that your contacts list is not too large in order to avoid performance issues. If it's too large you can split it and execute 2 calls and then merge them on the client side.

if you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Sir "Ran Hassid" I do it but in my Logcat I received this log
" I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: I guess the reason is that you are not execute the request async .. Can you please paste your code to the question ?

Comment: Stack overflow did not accept my answer I think I am new on Stack overflow can you share your email id I send code on email.

Comment: Please post it to some web editor on the web and send me the link you can use https://jsfiddle.net